# Splitter in Golang

Tags: java, string, go, split

Below is the **Java** code, I need something similar in **Go**:

```
List<String> tokens = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("[]//"))
.trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(entry.getValue()))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`[//]`)
tokens := re.Split(entry, -1)
```

Comment: And what have you tried doing?

Comment: re := regexp.MustCompile(`[//]`)

tokens :=re.Split(entry,-1)

Comment: Relevant code should be [edit]ed into your question, not posted in the comments. Also it should be posted as a [mcve] and explain where exactly the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regexp is usually slower than doing it manually. Since the task is not complex, the non-regexp solution isn't complicated either.

You may use [`strings.FieldsFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc) to split a string on a set of characters, and [`strings.TrimSpace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) to strip off leading and trailing white-spaces.

Here's a simple function doing what you want:

```
func split(s, sep string) (tokens []string) {
    fields := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
        return strings.IndexRune(sep, r) != -1
    })
    for _, s2 := range fields {
        s2 = strings.TrimSpace(s2)
        if s2 != "" {
            tokens = append(tokens, s2)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", split("a,b;c, de; ; fg ", ",;"))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", split("a[b]c[ de/ / fg ", "[]/"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lRW3aPnhHuC)):

```
["a" "b" "c" "de" "fg"]
["a" "b" "c" "de" "fg"]
```

### Improvements

If performance is an issue and you have to call this `split()` function many times, it would be profitable to create a set-like map from the separator characters, and reuse that, so inside the function passed to `strings.FieldFunc()`, you can simply check if the `rune` is in this map, so you would not need to call `strings.IndexRune()` to decide if the given `rune` is a separator character.

The performance gain might not be significant if you have few separator characters (like 1-3 characters), but if you would have a lot more, using a map could significantly improve performance.

This is how it could look like:

```
var (
    sep1 = map[rune]bool{',': true, ';': true}
    sep2 = map[rune]bool{'[': true, ']': true, '/': true}
)

func split(s string, sep map[rune]bool) (tokens []string) {
    fields := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
        return sep[r]
    })
    for _, s2 := range fields {
        s2 = strings.TrimSpace(s2)
        if s2 != "" {
            tokens = append(tokens, s2)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", split("a,b;c, de; ; fg ", sep1))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", split("a[b]c[ de/ / fg ", sep2))
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SNqzjURHJjI).

Comment: Yes split on certain characters -> strings.FieldsFunc looks good.

Comment: Should be handy with more characters